# Parsing txt file with substring

Tags: sql, sql-server

I inherited a SQL code from my previous co-worker. The script was working the last time I ran it but it returns an error when I tried it today. Surprisingly the code is working on my colleague's PC. I double-check the SQL server database and we are using the same collation, Latin1_General_CS_AS. I did many tests, changing windows system locale etc however none of them work, the error is this:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 141
Invalid column name 'Value'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 141
Invalid column name 'Value'.
...
```

However, I couldn't get it! why it is working on one system and not on another! Does anybody has any idea or alternative solution for the substring part.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #VievingLive0
SELECT
 ProdDay, -- date
 HouseId, -- ID
 CAST(SUBSTRING(RowText, 2, CHARINDEX('_', RowText, 2)-2) AS INT) AS ChannelId, -- Channel ID
 CASE WHEN LEN(s.Value) = 14 THEN LEFT(s.Value, 2) ELSE STUFF(LEFT(s.Value, LEN(s.Value)-12), 3, 0, '_') END AS Individs, -- list of persons 
 (LEN(s.Value)-12)/2 AS CntIndiv, -- number of persons watching
 DATEADD(SECOND, substring(s.Value,LEN(s.Value)-11,2)*3600+substring(s.Value,LEN(s.Value)-9,2)*60+substring(s.Value,LEN(s.Value)-7,2), CAST(ProdDay AS DATETIME)) AS ViewFrom, -- time from
 DATEADD(SECOND, substring(s.Value,LEN(s.Value)-5 ,2)*3600+substring(s.Value,LEN(s.Value)-3,2)*60+substring(s.Value,LEN(s.Value)-1,2)+1, CAST(ProdDay AS DATETIME)) AS ViewTo -- time to
INTO #VievingLive0
FROM #All_TX4_files
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(SUBSTRING(RowText, PATINDEX('%_[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]%', SUBSTRING(RowText, 2, LEN(RowText)))+2, LEN(RowText)), '_') AS s -- extracting individual vieiwng statemenets from the row
WHERE LEFT(RowText, 1) = 'V' -- LIVE viewing rows
```

I am trying to parse this format txt:

```
H98500410_0
W1941.51
Pab_2467211514110343733611_W2898.81
V100_0_2_210_ab075700080859_ab081100081259_ab081700081959_ab082800083059_ab083400083559_ab110600110959_ab111300111459_ab113500115059_ab115300120259_ab120300120359_ab120400123059_ab123100123559_ab124800125359_ab173200173259_ab191200191359_ab191600191759
```

Comment: [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) definitely has a column `value`. You need to provide a [mre] here.

Comment: Side note: `WHERE RowText LIKE 'V%'` would be significantly more performant than `WHERE LEFT(RowText, 1)`, as the latter is non-SARGable.

Comment: The `CS` collation is a bit of a hint. `STRING_SPLIT`s column name is `value`, not `Value`. Check the server default collation as well (not just the database's), as you're using temporary objects.

Comment: Nice spot, @JeroenMostert , I hadn't noticed it is Case Sensitive. Though if both the OP and the other person are both using that collation, it would fail for both of them; which suggests that likely that statement isn't true.

Comment: @Larnu: they only mentioned database collation (where it's not clear if they meant collation of the database or the server, as those are easily confused); the collation of tempdb follows the server's, not the database you're in. I don't recall the exact rules for what happens when you start mixing and matching tempdb things with database things when the collations differ (sometimes this works, sometimes it doesn't), which is why I merely advised to check.

Comment: @Larnu A good reason why I always write my code case-sensitive, and that includes type names

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert. It was 2 issues , the first code was case-sensitive, although last time I ran the script it wasn't an issue! anyhow changing the s.Value to s.value fixed that chunk. the second you, were perfectly right, we had an identical database collation but different server collation